# How to insert a script after precompilation and before compilation with CMake?

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, clang++

I want to add a custom preprocessing step to the build process. What I want to happen is:

1. Regular preprocessing.
2. My custom script would run and transform the preprocessed output. Specifically, it will wrap functions marked with a `[[log]]` attribute with a logger that stores arguments and return value.
3. Continue compilation/linking of the altered files.

What options do I have using CMake and clang?

Comment: To whoever upvoted my answer or anyone that sees this, I've moved my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73575085/11107541) in preparation to flag this question as a duplicate. I need to have one upvote there before I can flag.